# When using "when" in my playbook, == works but != does not?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: testing statements
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }} is log01 or log02"
    when: ansible_hostname == "log01" or ansible_hostname == "log02"
```

The above works as shown in this output:

> > [root@ansible-host]# ansible-playbook test.yml
>
> PLAY [all]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [log01] ok: [web01] ok: [web02]
>
> TASK [testing statements]
>   ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************* skipping: [web01] skipping: [web02] ok: [log01] => {
>       "msg": "log01 is log01 or log02" }
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** log01                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0
>   failed=0 web01                      : ok=1    changed=0
>   unreachable=0    failed=0 web02                      : ok=1
>   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

But when I change the == to !=, which should reverse the output, it no longer works:

```
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: testing statements
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }} is log01 or log02"
    when: ansible_hostname != "log01" or ansible_hostname != "log02"
```

The output is now:

```
[root@ansible-host]# ansible-playbook test.yml
PLAY [all] 
TASK [Gathering Facts]
ok: [log01]
ok: [web02]
ok: [web01]
TASK [testing statements]
ok: [web01] => {
  "msg": "web01 is log01 or log02" }
ok: [web02] => {
  "msg": "web02 is log01 or log02" }
ok: [log01] => {
  "msg": "log01 is log01 or log02" }
PLAY RECAP
log01: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0   failed=0
web01: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0   failed=0
web02: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0   failed=0
```

Comment: `(== || ==) != !(!= || !=)`. I recommend checking out some helpful information on logical operators and sets and all that.

Comment: Why do you think != is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to have it not run the task when it is on the web01 host, then you need to use the and operator instead of the or.  If you are trying to skip the log01 or log02 hosts, you could rewrite your when like this:

```
when: '"log" not in ansible_hostname'
```

And that would catch any instance of log.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing.